# valid way to update a state property in react?

Tags: reactjs, state-management, react-state-management

Very new to react so I wanted to check if this is correct. I don't get errors, but just to make sure I'm doing this in the right way.

```
state = {
        results: [],
    };
```

This method updates the state upon reach:

```
searchRequestHandler = () => {
        const filterCopy = this.state.filter;
        const dogsCharacteristicsData = dataFromServerModelerUponSearch(
            this.props.dogs
        );

        const resultsFromFilter = filterDataResults(
            filterCopy,
            dogsCharacteristicsData
        );

        this.setState({ formIsOpen: false, results: [...resultsFromFilter] });
    };
```

I'm also very curious to know how this could be done with restructuring. Thank you!

Here is what the data looks in the console for resultsFromFilter variable:

[image]

Comment: Depends on `filterDataResults`, can you include that?

Comment: You mean results from filter? sure I will add an image of what it shows in the console, thanks

Comment: Please post the *code* - the implementation of `filterDataResults`. It'll look something like `const filterDataResults = (...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right while updating you result state.
There are other ways you can update your result array like this:

```
let result =  resultsFromFilter;
this.setState({ formIsOpen: false, results: result});
```

Or

```
this.setState({ formIsOpen: false, results:  resultsFromFilter  });
```